# Pandas adds columns to non-referenced dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This one has been blowing my mind for hours. Perhaps there's some arcane 'gotcha' I'm missing but it must be incredibly counter-intuitive.

'trial_unq' is a two column dataframe and 'trial_unq2' is an identical copy, the for loop loops over all strings in 'unique_in'. If a 'unique_in' is in the text of trial_unq less 250 times, then a boolean column is inserted to the end of trial_unq. If a unqiue_in is in the text of trial_unq more than 10000 times, then the boolean columnn is inserted into the end of trial_unq2.

```
trial_unq2 = trial_unq

for i in range(len(unique_in)):#for each individual word
    unq_count = trial_unq.brief_title.str.contains(unique_in[i]).sum()#count trial occurances
    print(unique_in[i], ' ', unq_count)
    if unq_count < 280 and unq_count > 0:
        colname = unique_in[i]
        colpos = len(trial_unq.columns)
        boolcol = trial_unq.brief_title.str.contains(unique_in[i])
        trial_unq.insert(colpos, colname, boolcol) 
    if unq_count > 10000:
        colname2 = unique_in[i]
        colpos2 = len(trial_unq2.columns)
        boolcol2 = trial_unq2.brief_title.str.contains(unique_in[i])
        trial_unq2.insert(colpos2, colname2, boolcol2) 

print(trial_unq.columns)
print(trial_unq2.columns)
```

Output

```
['depressive', 'disorder', 'depressive disorder', 'therapy']
depressive   257
disorder   2190
depressive disorder   167
therapy   12236
Index(['NCT', 'brief_title', 'depressive', 'depressive disorder', 'therapy'], dtype='object')
Index(['NCT', 'brief_title', 'depressive', 'depressive disorder', 'therapy'], dtype='object')
```

From the output it is clear that both the the small count trial_unq dataframe and the larger count trial_unq2 dataframe have all three columns added to them.

Comment: Not fully sure what your question is, but can you try `trial_unq2 = trial_unq.copy()` and see whether that solves the issue?

Comment: wow that worked. why???

Comment: I guess you need to read up on a couple of Python basics :). You can try: `l1 = [1, 2, 3]`, `l2 = l1`, `l2[1] = 100` and then print `l1`. Same happens above for your dataframes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have more of science/data background and dove over from R and skipped the basics...should have asked for help earlier, got thrown for a loop =(

Comment: No worries, I have a lot of colleagues having a matlab background, they ran into the same issues as you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, several names can refer to the same object, e.g.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = l1  # now both, l1 and l2 refer to the same object!
l2[1] = 100
```

now both, `l1` and `l2` look like this:

```
[1, 100, 3]
```

Same happens with your two dataframes.

In this case, you can simply use `.copy()`

```
l3 = l1.copy()
l3[1] = 0

l1
[1, 100, 3]

l3
[1, 0, 3]
```

So, to fix your issue, all you need is:

```
trial_unq2 = trial_unq.copy()
```